# XHR readyState = 4 but Status = 0 in Google Chrome Browser

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

Hello I've got a strange problem with an AJAX call on my site. I make a simple AJAX call to a script on my site. But the AJAX call fails with readyState = 4 and status = 0. There's no cross domain problem because the script I want to call is on my server.

```
$.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    url: 'http://mydomain.com/test.php',
                    success : function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    error : function(XHR){
                        console.log(arguments);
                    }
});
```

I've googled a lot of sites but there seems to be no solution for that!

Comment: is your site on www. or naked domain?

Comment: =>If you are facing this issue just do one thing first clear your browser session cookie
then add **"Math.rendom()"** in your url of ajax **Eg,
"sample.php?r=" + Math.random();** =>Is it the url written correct? If you write it as an absolute URL **(like http://www.etc)** it won't work. Is it a relative path there?

Comment: Did you find an answer? I am getting the same problem and mine is not a domain issue.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when the URL of the AJAX request has a different domain than the page the script is running in. For example, `www.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com` are different.

To fix it, replace

```
url: 'http://mydomain.com/test.php',
```

with

```
url: 'http://' + document.domain + '/test.php',
```

I found this question while looking for the answer myself. I got the solution from [here](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/04/ajax-readystate-is-4-but-statu.html).

Comment: I am getting the same error on a very simple page that works 99% of the time on production. But occasionally I get this error. The code has the exact same domain & protocol, it's easy to tell because the javascript is short and the url is hardcoded.